# Why is that the state of an ng-form within a directive does not propagate to an outer ng-form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

I have a myInputText directive that dynamically generates its template within the link function. It contains an input that has a ng-form around it. The input has the ng-required attribute set to true. The state of the input (e.g. ng-invalid-required) propagates to the ng-form inside the directive, but not to the ng-form outside of the directive.
Consider the case when the input is empty, therefore its class attribute has a value of ng-invalid ng-invalid-required, and so does the innerForm, but the outerForm is oblivious of that, being ng-pristine ng-valid.

```
<ng-form name="outerForm" id="outerForm">
    <my-input-text form-name="myForm0" field="myField0" app-model="myAppModel></my-input-text>
</ng-form>
```

Here's a plnkr to demonstrate the behavior:
http://plnkr.co/edit/8vGKRN4cJHs224uN2k9T?p=preview

Comment: you need to create separate form for your inner element, then only it will work..

Comment: did you try constructing the inner form in the compile phase using the `compile` property of the directive, rather than in the linking phase? It may be the case that the FormController is not picking up the dynamically generated fields due to them being appended too late in the process.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for a stripped down version of what I actually need to do. But I have a hard time getting around it since I cannot perform template manipulations that involve scope or data binding.